I want different pictures in the find a pair game, but I can't implement it
I created a Matchmaking game, but there's no way I can customize the buttons any other way. I wanted to create associations, for example, there is a button with rain and there is an umbrella button, but I can't normally enter this into the game, and all I have is the code for the usual "find a couple" game.
What I have:


What I want to do:


In this moment I use 2 code for work my game.
GameController.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const int columns = 4;
    public const int rows = 2;

    public const float Xspace = 4f;
    public const float Yspace = -3f;

    [SerializeField] private MainImageScripts startObject;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] images;

    private int[] Randomiser(int[] locations)
    {
        int[] array = locations.Clone() as int[];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int newArray = array[i];
            int j = Random.Range(i, array.Length);
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = newArray;
        }
        return array;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        int[] locations = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
        locations = Randomiser(locations);

        Vector3 startPosition = startObject.transform.position;

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                MainImageScripts gameImage;
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                {
                    gameImage = startObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    gameImage = Instantiate(startObject) as MainImageScripts;
                }

                int index = j * columns + i;
                int id = locations[index];
                gameImage.ChangeSprite(id, images[id]);

                float positionX = (Xspace * i) + startPosition.x;
                float positionY = (Yspace * j) + startPosition.y;

                gameImage.transform.position = new Vector3(positionX, positionY, startPosition.z);
            }
        }
    }

    private MainImageScripts firstOpen;
    private MainImageScripts secondOpen;

    private int score = 0;
    private int attempts = 0;

    [SerializeField] private TextMesh scoreText;
    [SerializeField] private TextMesh attemptsText;

    public bool canOpen
    {
        get { return secondOpen == null; }
    }

    public void imageOpened(MainImageScripts startObject)
    {
        if (firstOpen == null)
        {
            firstOpen = startObject;
        }
        else
        {
            secondOpen = startObject;
            StartCoroutine(CheckGuessed());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckGuessed()
    {
        if (firstOpen.spriteId == secondOpen.spriteId)
        {
            score++;
            scoreText.text = "Счёт: " + score;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

            firstOpen.Close();
            secondOpen.Close();
        }

        attempts++;
        attemptsText.text = "Попыток: " + attempts;

        firstOpen = null;
        secondOpen = null;
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
    }
}

MainImageScripts.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainImageScripts : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject image_unknown;
    [SerializeField] private GameController gameController;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (image_unknown.activeSelf && gameController.canOpen)
        {
            image_unknown.SetActive(false);
            gameController.imageOpened(this);
        }
    }
    private int _spriteId;

    public int spriteId
    {
        get { return _spriteId; }
    }
    public void ChangeSprite(int id, Sprite image)
    {
        _spriteId = id;
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = image;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        image_unknown.SetActive(true);
    }
}

I tried to remove the part from private int[] Randomiser(int[] locations) and added [SerializeField] int number so that I could give id buttons and pictures using the same method, but I'm too stupid to figure out how to fix it :(

well the obvious place to start is the arrage of "images"

This looks over complicated.  I think the main issue is this line: gameImage.ChangeSprite(id, images[id]);  since id is one of the locations, and you have duplicates for those locations, meaning the same image will be used twice rather than separate matching images.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This would be easier with the use of a class that holds the matching images.  You could do this using ScriptableObject so they can be reused.  This allows you to add more data such as a name, fx, audio, etc.
public class ImageSet : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite sprite1;
    public Sprite sprite2;

    // additional metadata and properties..
}

In your controller class, make an array of those and assign them in the inspector.
To assign the sprites to locations, create a list of location indices (0 through (sets * 2)), and shuffle it.
Loop over all of the image sets, take 2 locations, create the game images and configure them accordingly.
pseudo code
[SerializeField] private ImageSet[] imageSets;

private void Start()
{
    // construct a list of all location indices
    //
    var locations = Enumerable.Range(0, imageSets.Length * 2).ToList(); // { 0, 1, 2, etc.. }

    // Shuffle the locations list
    //
    locations.Shuffle();

    // loop over all the image sets
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < imageSets.Length; i++)
    {
        var imageSet = imageSets[i];
        
        var location1 = locations[i * 2];
        var location2 = locations[i * 2 + 1];

        var gameImage1 = CreateGameImage();
        var gameImage2 = CreateGameImage();
        
        gameImage1.SetSprite(i, imageSet.sprite1);
        gameImage2.SetSprite(i, imageSet.sprite2);
        
        gameImage1.transform.position = GetLocationPosition(location1);
        gameImage2.transform.position = GetLocationPosition(location2);
    }
}

